# Media Player socket exception in Samsung Grand

Tags: android, media-player, samsung-mobile, socketexception

we are playing media through a local proxy server. Everything was fine till the new Samsung Grand device. In that specific device we are getting a Socket exception as following:

```
4-04 17:55:35.646: W/System.err(15187): java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
04-04 17:55:35.646: W/System.err(15187):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:506)
04-04 17:55:35.646: W/System.err(15187):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:475)
04-04 17:55:35.646: W/System.err(15187):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
04-04 17:55:35.656: W/System.err(15187):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
04-04 17:55:35.656: W/System.err(15187):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
04-04 17:55:35.656: W/System.err(15187):    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:185)
04-04 17:55:35.656: W/System.err(15187):    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:139)
04-04 17:55:35.656: W/System.err(15187):    at com.ganeshane.music.gslib.comp.security.SecurityManager$EncryptDecryptAgent.decryptStreamWithHeaderAndFlush(SecurityManager.java:192)
04-04 17:55:35.656: W/System.err(15187):    at com.ganeshane.music.gslib.comp.player.ProxyMediaPlayer$LocalFileServer.handleGetRequest(ProxyMediaPlayer.java:315)
04-04 17:55:35.656: W/System.err(15187):    at com.ganeshane.music.gslib.comp.player.ProxyMediaPlayer$LocalFileServer.run(ProxyMediaPlayer.java:291)
04-04 17:55:35.656: W/System.err(15187): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
04-04 17:55:35.666: W/System.err(15187):    at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
04-04 17:55:35.666: W/System.err(15187):    at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:146)
04-04 17:55:35.666: W/System.err(15187):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
04-04 17:55:35.666: W/System.err(15187):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:473)
04-04 17:55:35.666: W/System.err(15187):    ... 8 more
```

Our get and head headers are:

```
              HEAD = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" + Date + "\r\n"
                + "Last-Modified: Mon, 19 Jan 20013 12:51:42 GMT\r\n"
                + "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
                + "Content-Type: audio/mpeg\r\n"
                + "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n"
                + "Server: Apache/2.2.9\r\n" + "Content-Length: "
                + fileLength + "\r\n" + "\r\n";

          GET = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" + Date + "\r\n"
                + "Last-Modified: Mon, 19 Jan 20013 12:51:42 GMT\r\n"
                + "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
                + "Content-Type: audio/mpeg\r\n"
                + "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n"
                + "Server: Apache/2.2.9\r\n" + "Content-Length: "
                + fileLength + "\r\n" + "\r\n";
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: here the filelength is a integer containing the origional content legth.

Comment: Hi..even I'm facing the same issue... Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: yep, just don't sent all the song data in a single request.

Comment: @JaiPandit can you please expound some more? same problem here

Comment: @frostymarvelous .. did you find the solution ? you can paste your code..

Answer (score 0):

So, my solution was for Encrypted mp3 files, but should work for other uses. The only issue I have faced is seeking when buffering is not complete. I am sure there is some range end request, but I really don't care. It works 99.9% of the time so...

below is the relevant response headers part, but you can find the entire code at https://gist.github.com/frostymarvelous/26ac6cba11bf50e591a4

```
if (cbSkip > 0) {// It is a seek or skip request if there's a Range
            // header
            headers += "HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content\r\n";
            headers += "Content-Type: " + dataSource.getContentType() + "\r\n";
            headers += "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n";
            headers += "Content-Length: " + (fileSize - cbSkip) + "\r\n";
            headers += "Content-Range: bytes " + cbSkip + "-" + (fileSize - 1) + "/" + fileSize + "\r\n";
            headers += "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n";
            headers += "\r\n";
        } else {
            headers += "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
            headers += "Content-Type: " + dataSource.getContentType() + "\r\n";
            headers += "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n";
            headers += "Content-Length: " + fileSize + "\r\n";
            headers += "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n";
            headers += "\r\n";
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "headers: " + headers);

        OutputStream output = null;
        byte[] buff = new byte[64 * 1024];
        try {
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream(), 32 * 1024);
            output.write(headers.getBytes());
            InputStream data = dataSource.getInputStream();

            dataSource.skipFully(data, cbSkip);//try to skip as much as possible

            // Loop as long as there's stuff to send and client has not closed
            int cbRead;
            while (!client.isClosed() && (cbRead = data.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) != -1) {
                output.write(buff, 0, cbRead);
            }
        }
```